# Check collision between two imported pictures

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

I'm trying to recreate a game, however all I need is to create a game-over feature that occurs when the player collides or fails to jump over the rock. I've tried to do the check collision yet the player is passing through. What should I do or change in order to display the game over screen when the player collides with the rock? Here is my sample code:

```
#---  Player Definition 
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    #- Constructor
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.playing = False
        self.image = pygame.image.load("bcquestchar.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.color = BLUE
        self.rect.x = 50
        self.rect.y = 210
        self.goalY= 450
        self.gameover = False
    #- Allows Player to Jump
    def jump(self):
        self.goalY -= 25
    #- Imports & Displays player_image
    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(player_image, [self.rect.x, self.rect.y])

#--- Rock definition
class Rock(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    #- Constructor
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("bcrocks.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = random.randrange (0, 200)
        self.rect.y = 335
    #- Moves Rock
    def move(self):
        self.rect.x -= 3
    #- Imports & Displays rock_image
    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, [self.rect.x + 700, self.rect.y])
# Loop until user closes pygame 
done = False

# How fast the screen updates
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Creates player
rock = Rock()
player = Player()
obstacles = pygame.sprite.Group()
obstacles.add(rock)

if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, obstacles, False):
    player.gameover = True

#----- Main Program Loop -----#
while not done:
    #movesound.play()
    #- Calls in draw_background function
    draw_background (screen, 0, 0)
    #- Tracks Events
    speed = 1
#--- Main Event Loop
    for event in pygame.event.get(): 
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            done = False

#- User is playing when M1 is clicked
    elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:  
        player.playing = True

    #- User jumps when playing and has not lost
    if(player.gameover == False and player.playing == True):
        player.jump()

#- Is the player playing?
if(player.playing == True):

    # Jump up when the up arrow is pressed
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        currently_jumping = True
        going_up = True
        #hopsound.play()

    if currently_jumping == True:
        if player.rect.y < 188:
            going_up = False
        elif going_up == False and player.rect.y > 215:
            currently_jumping = False

        if going_up:
            player.rect.y -= 2
        elif going_up == False:
            player.rect.y += 2

    elif currently_jumping == False:
        if(player.rect.y > 600 or player.rect.y < 0):
            player.gameover = True    
        if(player.rect.y < 210):#player.goalY):
            player_moving_up = False

        elif(player.rect.y > 210):#player.goalY):
            player_moving_up = True

        if player_moving_up == True or player_moving_up == True:
            player.rect.y += 1
            player.rect.y -= 1
        player.goalY += 3


    if(timer3 > 120):
        timer3 = 0
        if(player.playing == True and player.gameover == False):
            score += 30

    #--- Draw and Move Rocks
    for rock in obstacles:
        rock.draw(screen)
        if(player.gameover == False):
            rock.move()
            rock.draw(screen)
            #rock.checkCollision(player.x, player.y)
        if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, obstacles, False):
            obstacles.remove(rock)
#----- Gameover        
        if(player.gameover == True):
            player.goalY = 600
            font = pygame.font.SysFont('Ariel', 50, True, False)
            text = font.render("Game Over", True, WHITE)
            screen.blit(text, [150, 100])
```

Code edited

Comment: use `pygame.Rect`. It has `colliderect()` metod.

Comment: read this: http://programarcadegames.com/

Answer (score 0):

Make `Rock()` also a `pygame.sprite.Sprite` class and if possible, put in a `pygame.sprite.Group()`. In that case, you can use `if pygame.sprite.spritecollide()` to check for detection:

```
rock = Rock()
player = Player()
obstacles = pygame.sprite.Group()
obsatcles.add(rock)
if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, obstacles, False):
    pass #Do something
```

The good thing about using `pygame.sprite.Group()` is that you can use that to help detect collisions with the player and any other obstacle. Let's assume you have three items in `obstacles`, in which they are all `rock`'s:

```
for rock in obstacles:
    if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, obstacles, False):
        obstacles.remove(rock)  #Removes the obstacle
```

Put the group outside the sprite classes and before the while loop.

For the rock, use this in your init function:

```
self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

So it would be:

```
def __init__(self):
     pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
     self.image = pygame.image.load("filename.png")
     self.rect = pygame.image.get_rect()
```

Then add this to your while loop:

```
for rock in obstacles:
    rock.move()
    rock.draw()
```

Your final class (excluding the last two functions) would be:

```
class Rock(pygames.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("bcrocks.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = random.randrange (0, 200)
        self.rect.y = 335
```

Comment: Thank you for replying! So if I were to make Rock() a pygame.sprite.Sprite class, I would do the same like how I did for Player() right?

Comment: Another question, (I apologize) where do I put pygame.sprite.Group()? Under the constructor function for rock?

Comment: I tried to make `Rock()` a sprite class but the `'rock'` object has no attribute `'rect'`. Is this correct ?: `self.rect.x = random.randrange (0, 200)`

Comment: Okay, I used the `self.rect = pygame.image.get_rect()` instead of `self.rect.x` and `self.rect.y` for some reason the module object has no `'get_rect'`

Comment: Cheers, I ran the code but it says `'rock'` object has no attribute `'image'` so it's okay if i put `self.image = pygame.image.load("bcrocks.png")` just above `self.rect = self.image.get_rect()`

Comment: Correct and put it in the constructor function

Comment: Okay! I really appreciate your help, I did everything you suggested and I edited the code above, the rocks don't appear on the screen nor collides with the player?

Comment: You have to keep everything the same but add those two lines, changing the filename to the appropriate one

Comment: Okay so instead of `self.rect = self.image.get_rect()` I replace it with `self.rect = pygame.image.get_rect()` under the rock class? Do I also remove `self.rect.x` and `self.rect.y`?

Comment: Implemented changes above, the rocks seem to still not show up?

Comment: yup i put `rock.draw(screen)` under `#--- Draw and Move Rocks`

Comment: Don't you mean `screen.blit(rock.image, rock.rect)`?

Comment: Under the `class Rock` or down below with the `for rock in obstacles`?

Comment: The function `draw()`

Comment: Oookay, I made the change to `screen.blit(rock.image, rock.rect)` but it still doesn't show up

Comment: Change the parameters of `draw(self, screen)` to `draw(self)`

Comment: I changed the parameters, yet the same error is occuring. Another odd thing is when I first launch the game, it brings it to the game over screen, restarts and then continues